# Как вывести на экран массивы четных и нечетных чисел?

Tags: java, arraylist

```java
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    //статическая инициализация массива
    int[] data = {1, 5, 6, 11, 3, 15, 7, 8};

    //создание списка, где все элементы должны быть типа Integer
    ArrayList<Integer> list = new ArrayList<Integer>();

    //заполнение списка из массива
    for (int i = 0; i < data.length; i++) list.add(data[i]);

    ArrayList<Integer> even = new ArrayList<Integer>();   // чётные
    ArrayList<Integer> odd = new ArrayList<Integer>();    // нечётные

    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        Integer x = list.get(i);
        if (x % 2 == 0)    // если x - чётное
            even.add(x);   // добавляем x в коллекцию четных чисел
        else
            odd.add(x);    // добавляем x в коллекцию нечетных чисел
    }
}
```

Comment: ну если вы этот код сами написали, то неужто вывод на экран это для вас такая сложная задача? :)

Comment: Нет не сам)) JavaRush. Решаю похожую задачу., вроде решил по образу и подобию этой, а вот вывести никак не могу(((

Comment: even.stream().forEach(System.out::println)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Переписал код с использованием [`Arrays.stream`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#stream-int:A-) и [`StringBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html). Вывод в строку:

```java
int[] data = new int[]{1, 5, 6, 11, 3, 15, 7, 8};

StringBuilder even = new StringBuilder(); // чётные
StringBuilder odd = new StringBuilder();  // нечётные

Arrays.stream(data).forEach(e -> {
    if (e % 2 == 0) {
        even.append(e).append(",");
    } else {
        odd.append(e).append(",");
    }
});

System.out.println(even.toString()); // 6,8,
System.out.println(odd.toString());  // 1,5,11,3,15,7,
```

Answer (score 0):

Выведет в столбик :

```
for (Integer number : even) {
  System.out.println(number);
}

for (Integer number : odd) {
  System.out.println(number);
}
```

Выведет в строчку :

```
for (Integer number : even) {
  System.out.print(number + " ");
}

for (Integer number : odd) {
  System.out.print(number + " ");
}
```

=)))

Comment: Огромное спасибо, задачку решил.

Comment: @Александр плюсик поставьте , буду благодарен